# Rename pdf rename pdf files with their text content in a specific location

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-rename

I can't find the way to rename files with the `enumerate` function.
Example:

```
for position, line in enumerate(pdf_text):
    lines_to_read = [1280,1281,1282,1283,1284,1285,1286,1287,1288,1289,1290,1291]
    if position in lines_to_read
        print(line,end="") 
        # I can print the text sequence at specific conditions
        pdf_file_obj.close()
        # but i've not success for use the print output as file name 
        os.rename(fullpath,+ "??" + ".pdf")
```

How can I transform the string in output to be able to use it as filename?

Comment: Hey @Guiseppe, I am not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve. Do you want to rename the file to the content of the respective line? or the line number itself? In the first case, ``os.rename(fullpath,'%s.pdf'%line)`` should do the job. In general, I would recommend posting https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example .

Answer (score 0):

thanks for answering me.

My idea is to rename pdf files dynamically based on their content in the specific location (of the same pdf file). Since these are pay slips, all files have the employee's registration number and name in the same position.

```
import os, PyPDF2, re
def rename_pdfs(extraced_pdf_folder, rename_folder):
# traverse down through the root directory to sub-directories
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(extraced_pdf_folder):
for filename in files:
basename, extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
# if a file is a pdf

# if extension == ".pdf":
#   # create a reference to the full filename path
fullpath = root + "\\" + basename + extension
#   # open the individual pdf
pdf_file_obj = open(fullpath, "rb")
pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file_obj)
#   # access the individual page
page_obj = pdf_reader.getPage(0)
#   # extract the the text
pdf_text = page_obj.extractText()
# use enumerate to find information
for position, line in enumerate(pdf_text):
lines_to_read [1280,1281,1282,1283,1284,1285,1286,1287,1288,1289,1290,1291
       ,1292,1293,1294,1295,1296,1297,1298,1299,1300,1301,1302,1303,1304,1305,1306,13 
07,1308]
doc_num = "nome "
pdf_file_obj.close()
          
if position in lines_to_read:
    #THIS PRINT IN THE CONSOLE FOR EACH PDF THE EMPLYE NAME AND SURNAME
    print (line,end="")
    #OS RENAME WITH %LINE GIVE ME ONLY A CARACTER

    os.rename(fullpath, root + "\\" + doc_num + "%s.pdf"%line)
    
    # parameter variables
    root_dir = r"C:\query\pdf\rename_pdf"
    extract_to = r"C:\query\pdf\extracted"
    rename_to = r"C:\query\pdf\renamed"

    

    rename_pdfs(extract_to,rename_to)
```

Comment: hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! It seems you have posted an update to your question as an answer, would you mind editing your question to include this info. Also if you want to format the code be sure to paste it in with correct indentation then highlight it all and hit the code `{}` formatting button or use control+k to correctly format it. You seem to have some indentation issues.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using chained regexes.

I thank you all

```
for index in re.finditer("SHERAZ0101", pdf_text):
  #oc_ext = pdf_text[index.start()+506:index.start()+531]
  doc_ext = pdf_text[index.end()+488:index.end()+521] +pdf_text[index.end()+471:index.end()+477]
  
  doc_num = "" + doc_ext.replace('\n\n',"").replace('/',"-").replace('SPECI',"").replace(":","").replace("  ", "").replace(" .pdf",".pdf")
  pdf_file_obj.close()
  print(doc_ext)
  # rename the pdf based on the information in the pdf
  os.rename(fullpath, rename_folder + "\\" + doc_num + ".pdf")
```